# Same column has two different date formats in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

In my oracle db, I have a date field, `TDATE`. The format for some entries is

`dd-MM-YYYY` and for some, it is `MM-dd-YYYY`. And some places it will be some

other format like `YYYY-MM-dd` or `YYYY-MMM-dd`. It can be anything.
Can someone tell me how to

change them to `dd-MM-YYYY`?

Comment: `select sysdate from dual;` run this query and you will get the standard format of your DB. Then you can change it by using `alter session.....`

Comment: `It can be anything` Sorry, I don't think there's a way to convert literally anything to dd-mm-yyyy. We can't even differentiate between dd-mm and mm-dd in some cases. I suggest that you concentrate on specific examples. Also, what is the type of `tdate`? Is it varchar?

Comment: An additional edge case problem: does `10-09-2018` mean September 10th or October 9th?  By the way, SQL Server has a `TRY_CONVERT` function, which would actually cycle through all possible masks, but maybe Oracle does not have such a function.

Comment: Another example showing that you should **never** store date/time values as *strings*. You question must me "Can someone tell me how to change them to `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) format?"

Comment: If you have locale informtion for each row, you can convert them to right format. Otherwise, as @TimBiegeleisen mentioned, it is not possible to tell 10-09-2018 as whether it is 10th September or 9th October.